# Is there a way, while dragging, to "snap" to the nearest guide?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, snapping

I'm copy, paste and dragging some group of elements. While I'm dragging, I'd like to "snap" to the nearest guide I've set in the workspace.

Else, I need to zoom and move the key arrow to reach exactly the limit I need.

Is there a way to help my drag with guides?
Also, is there a way to show a sort of "hints" showing the pixels distance between a group and the object I'm moving? I often space of about 5 pixels.

Answer (score 8):

Use the **Smart Guides** to get all this info. To activate the **Smart Guides** press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> Win.

[image]

Comment: but it doesn't show the distance between two objects being copied :(

Comment: any way? Such as when I drag, show  how many pixels there are between the dragged elements and the objects around it? For example, I need grid elements spaced 8 pixels y and 5 x

Comment: As you can see in the animation, there's a *dx* and a *dy* number, this is the *x* and *y* distance you are moving away from the original position

Comment: Yes, but its not what I'm looking for. I need dx/dy.against the nearest objects. So if the nearest is at 10 pixels and I move around it, I'll see 9, 8, etc . Once I got 8, I stop dragging :) Is it possibile?

Answer (score 3):

@Danielillo's answer is the first and best option if it works. Unfortunately, occasionally the smart guides do not snap to the guide or object that you want. If this happens, you have a couple of options:

1. Select the entire object, then switch to the direct select tool
   (white arrow). Click and hold on one of the object's anchor point,
   then drag the object to the nearest guide to snap the selected anchor point to the
   guide. When dragging a single point, smart guides should use that
   point as the snapping reference.

    or
2. Make sure your guides are unlocked. Select the object and the guide,
   then use the alignment panel to align the object to the guide.